# В хроме в мобильной версии непонятные стили

Tags: css

```
    /*
.lleo_errorSelection *::-moz-selection,
.lleo_errorSelection *::selection,
.lleo_errorSelection *::-webkit-selection {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  ;
}
*/
#lleo_dialog,
#lleo_dialog * {
  color: #000 !important;
  font: normal 13px Arial, Helvetica !important;
  line-height: 15px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background: none !important;
  border: none 0 !important;
  position: static !important;
  vertical-align: baseline !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  width: auto
}
```

В мобильной версии перед страницей прописан этот код перед контентом.
[Ссылка на сайт](https://pampering-multitask.000webhostapp.com/template5/)
Что это, как убрать? В файлах конечно у меня ничего такого нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это содержимое динамически добавляется плагином LinguaLeo на каждую загружаемую страницу.

> как убрать?

Отключить плагин LinguaLeo в настройках браузера, расширения.